# Xamarin - SignaturePad BackgroundImageView trouble

Tags: xamarin, background-image, signaturepad

Having trouble getting this to work - I must be missing something:

```
signaturePad2.BackgroundImageView = new ImageView(Context)
{
   Id = GenerateId(this),
   LayoutParameters = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent)
};

signaturePad2.AddView(BackgroundImageView);
signaturePad2.BackgroundImage = MyGlobals.FileNameOfPhotoTaken;
```

Comment: What's the problem? What's the expected result?

Comment: I cannot compile.  It looks like it is Android specific code I found.  Many errors in regards to items not existing in the current context.  I am referencing Xamarin.Controls & Forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BackgroundImage` is of type `ImageSource`

```
padView.BackgroundImage = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri(
    "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f2/Xamarin-logo.svg/220px-Xamarin-logo.svg.png"));
```

Comment: Tried this (deleted everything after it), but get an error:  Unhandled Exception:

System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid. occurred

Comment: I did change "padView" to "signaturePad2" which is what I called the signature pad on my XAML.  Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: This is the line in "SignaturePadView.cs" that had the problem:   propertyChanged: (bindable, oldValue, newValue) => ((SignaturePadView)bindable).BackgroundImageView.Source = (ImageSource)newValue);

Comment: Do I need to have the file "SignaturePadView.cs" in my project?  Maybe that is the problem.

Comment: No.  Are you sure you're using the correct (and latest) package for signatures?  Are you doing this code in your shared project or in your platform project?

Comment: I am pretty sure I have tge latest package. At one time I created a "SignaturePadView.cs" file and added all the methods fron the GRIT page. Should I delete that?  Right now all the files are in the shared project. Is that where these signaturepad files should be?

Comment: Ah - I see I need to delete that .cs file. I'll do that tomorrow - i have a real early start tomorrow. Thank you